# Append table row with user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table of data as follows-

```
<table class="table" id = "myTable>
    <tr>
      <td> <b> ID </b> </td>
      <td> <b> First Name </b> </td>
      <td> <b> Last Name </b> </td>
    </tr>
```

And I have an input form section as follows-

```
<form>
      <input type="text" id ="userID">
      <input type="text" id ="firstname">
      <input type="text" id ="lastname">
      <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Can someone help me out with the javascript required to append a new row to my table containing data gained from the user input form?

Comment: Would you mind using jquery

Comment: Yup. jQuery all the things

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Either your markup has a typo or it is invalid.

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/97ZpN/1/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need jQuery to do that. Just use javascript.
You can use a function like this:

HTML with function on click of submit button..

```
<table class="table" id = "myTable">
    <tr>
      <td> <b> ID </b> </td>
      <td> <b> First Name </b> </td>
      <td> <b> Last Name </b> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<form action="">
    <input type="text" id ="userID" />
    <input type="text" id ="firstname" />
    <input type="text" id ="lastname" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return fillTable();" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
function fillTable() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("userID").value;
  cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
  cell3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
  return false;
}
```

[I've build a JSFiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/a7FBK/) to illustrate the behavior.